# Synchronized block on two threads in Swing not working

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, rendering, game-engine

Let me describe to you the context of my problem before I outline the issue. I'm currently in the middle of writing a game engine level editor and I'm working on the class that is going to act as the screen that the user interacts with in order to build their levels. I want to make it so the screen is proportional to the size of the editor.

The issue in question occurs when I begin resizing my screen and drawing on it at the same time. I draw from one thread and at the same time I'm editing the size of the raw pixel array that I'm drawing onto, from another thread (the EDT). I know this is a big no-no so naturally, with no safety in place, I get the occasional IndexOutOfBounds Exception on a resize.

My thought was, I could add a synchronize block on both the resizing code and the drawing code. This way, there would be no conflict and the issue should be avoided. However, the synchronization is being ignored completely. I'm still getting the same error and I'm really quite confused on why it isn't working. Below are the two methods of interest:

```
public void setPixel(int r, int g, int b, int x, int y) {
    synchronized (pixels){
        System.out.println("Start Draw...");
        int color = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        pixels[y * screenWidth + x] = color;
        System.out.println("End Draw...");
    }
}


@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        synchronized (pixels) {
            System.out.println("Start resize");
            int width = e.getComponent().getWidth();
            int height = e.getComponent().getHeight();
            float aspectRatio = 4 / 3f;
            if (width > height) {
                width = (int) (height * aspectRatio);
            } else if (height > width) {
                height = width;
            }
            if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
                width = 1;
                height = 1;
            }
            this.screenWidth = width;
            this.screenHeight = height;
            image = new BufferedImage(screenWidth, screenHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
            System.out.println("End Resize");
        }
    }
```

I don't know if it matters (it shouldn't right?) but my screen class extends a AWT Canvas. Also it is a listener on its parent component, so when that gets resized, it fires an event that triggers componentResized to be called. Anyway, thank you, any help is appreciated.

EDIT: My drawing code can be found below.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            for (int y = 0; y < screen.getHeight(); y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < screen.getWidth(); x++){
                    int r = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                    int g = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                    screen.setPixel(r, g, b, x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I would recommend synchronizing on **final** properties. In your code, you are synchronizing in the *pixels* array which changes inside every synchronized block. So you are synchronizing to something that is not the same between calls of *setPixel* and *componentResized*.

Comment: Duh! You guys are totally right on that. I know this isn't the main case of the problem though because I've tried synchronizing on "Screen.class" before and other objects that you would assume are final. I also tried adding a dummy object to synchronize on `private final Object lock;` and initialized in the constructor as `lock = new Object();` Despite using this idea, I'm still getting an IndexOutOfBounds Exception. Any further ideas?

Comment: Why not use [`BufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB-int-int-int-) inside the *setPixel* method? This way you won't have to access the DataBufferInt manually. You will then have to maintain only the reference to the BufferedImage instead of the *pixels* array.

Comment: I don't know how exactly TYPE_INT_RGB is packed into integers. My idea though is that maybe only 3 bytes are actually needed for the rgb value internally (in the DataBufferInt object), so *getData* actually returns 3/4 the size of the array. So to solve this, maybe use TYPE_INT_ARGB (which is definitely going to map a single int to a full argb value) or use *BufferedImage.setRGB(...)* inside the *setPixel* method.

Comment: The body of your `while (true)` loop will run dozens, or hundreds, of times per second.  Is that really what you want?  Why would you need to execute it that frequently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something else I can think of. Not only what is in the comments of the question.

Let me modify first the `setPixel` method:

```
public void setPixel(int r, int g, int b, int x, int y) {
    System.out.println("Called with: " + x + ", " + y); //Just added a print statement.
    synchronized (mySyncGuard){
        System.out.println("Start Draw...");
        int color = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        pixels[y * screenWidth + x] = color;
        System.out.println("End Draw...");
    }
}
```

Where *mySyncGuard* is a final property used as the synchronization guard to both `setPixel` and `componentResized`.

And now imagine the following scenario:

There is a loop which calls the `setPixel` method: this loop calls the method starting from `x = 0` and `y = 0` up to `x < screenWidth` and `y < screenHeight`! Like the following one:

```
for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; ++x)
    for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; ++y) {
        int r = calculateNextR(),
            g = calculateNextG(),
            b = calculateNextB();
        setPixel(r, g, b, x, y);
    }
```

Where calculateNextR(), calculateNextG() and calculateNextB() are methods that produce the next red, green and blue color components respectively.

Now, for example, let *screenWidth* be 200 and *screenHeight* be also 200 and at some point resized to 100x100.

Now the problem is that x and y would be lets say 150 and 150 respectively while the component was about to be resized to 100, 100.

Our custom `setPixel` method is now called with x==150 and y==150. **But** before the printing statement we added which shows the x and the y values, the `componentResized` manages to be called and take the lock of the synchronization guard property *mySyncGuard*! So `componentResized` is now doing its job changing the size of the image to 100x100, which, in turn, changes the *pixels* array to something *smaller* than the previous data array.

In parallel, `setPixel` now prints *"Called with 150, 150"* and waits at the synchronized block to obtain the lock of *mySyncGuard*, because `componentResized` has already currently obtained it and changing the image to 100x100 and the *pixels* array accordingly.

So now the *pixels* array is smaller, the `componentResized` finishes resizing and finally setPixel can obtain the lock of mySyncGuard.

And now is the problem: the array pixels is traversed at location 150,150 while it actually has size 100x100. So there you go! IndexOutOfBoundsException...

**Conclusion**:

1. We need more of your code to determine what's wrong.
2. The variables changing (such as *screenWidth*, *screenHeight*, *image* and *pixels*) need to be synchronized everywhere, not only inside the `setPixel` and `componentResized` methods. For example, if your case is like the scenario I just described, then unfortunately the for loops should also be in a `synchronized (mySyncGuard)` block.
3. This wouldn't fit in a comment. If you post some more code, then we can probably tell you what went wrong (and I may delete this answer if it is not needed).

Comment: Wow. I think you're spot on in your analysis. I completely missed that. Let me paste you my drawing code. This code is called from the EDT but as you can see it starts its own thread.

EDIT: Too long for a comment, I'll append it to my original question.

Comment: UPDATE: Thank you! That totally worked. Although the result is messy since I'm blocking the EDT really hard so Swing has to wait until all of of the pixels in the Screen are iterated through which can take a while. Is there some way I can temporary stop the screen from rendering until my re-sizing is done, and then continue painting on the canvas? Maybe something like a wait and notify? I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: @K.Zoe sorry but I'm not an expert on drawing. This is almost a question I have too (how to not block the EDT so much with synchronized blocks). Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: @K.Zoe an idea I can think of is to probably use two BufferedImages. One for painting/drawing and one for rendering. While you are painting the one image, you render the other (which was previously painted). When you are done painting the offscreen image you switch the images. And then start again. That switching of the images is going to take up less time. I think though this already exists as an idea named "double buffering" and is already implemented in JPanels. Just use the proper constructor of the JPanel to enable double buffering. I really don't know anything else. May others help us.

Comment: So the double buffering idea is interesting but I'm not sure if it would fix the main issue. The problem is that the synchronize block doesn't have any inherent "fairness" about which thread it gives the lock to. So the thread that's executing the SetPixel() for loop can get priority many times over the EDT which is doing the resizing, causing the EDT to block for a long time. So the solution to this is to use a ReentrantLock which can be initialized to be "fair" which guarantees that each thread will take turns with the lock one after another (from my understanding at least)!

Comment: @K.Zoe I understand what you are saying. I don't really know how fair is the synchronizing mechanism in Java. Which means it may be fair! Who told us it is not? It is possible that it is fair enough. There is another way of solving this "fairness" manually though. Just use wait/notify plus a flag which will indicate whether it is time to paint/draw or to render (also from my understanding at least).

Comment: @K.Zoe for example lets say the flag is a boolean variable named *render*. If it is true, then you render. Otherwise (if it is false) you draw on the offscreen BufferedImage. So when *render* is true, call mySyncGuard.wait() inside the synchronized drawing block. This will guarantee that the drawing Thread will wait and not request the lock again until it is notified. Meanwhile the only Thread left to take the lock is the rendering one. So its gets the lock and renders and then notifies the drawing Thread. And process keeps going back and forth (at least from my understanding).

Comment: @K.Zoe although I don't think getting the EDT to *.wait()* is a good idea. :( I don't know if I can help you on this.

Comment: You're totally right on that, but, it works well enough for my purposes. I don't need complete responsiveness. I'll try and think of a better solution later that doesn't block the EDT but for now this will do. You've helped me solve the main issue and that's plenty already. Thank you for your time and help! :)